# Mount USB : permission Denied in a docker

Tags: docker, mount, permission-denied

I have created a Docker container and I want to mount a USB Key only in the container.

I have used the flag `--privilegied` and it works but I don't want to use this flag. Is there another solution ?

When I don't use the privileged flag I get:

```
root@2865bd86f958:/# mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/
mount: /mnt: permission denied.
```

Comment: Could you share the exact command you used to create the container? For example the whole `docker run` command?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @michalhosna. I use : docker run -tid  --rm --name clamav  --device=/dev/ttyUSB0 clamav:1.2

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the capability : SYS_ADMIN when you use the command run.

Now i can mount the usb but i can t write on it.

Someone has an idear ?